# SeektoTime not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

To pause and resume video i"m using the below code. but its not resuming from where it left. can anyone help me?

```
-(void)appEnteredBackground:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [playerViewController.player pause];
    currentTime = [playerViewController.player currentTime];
}

-(void)appEnteredForeground:(NSNotification*)notification {

    if(playerViewController.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay &&
       self.playerViewController.player.currentItem.status ==  AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
       total_duration = self.playerViewController.player.currentItem.duration;
       [self.playerViewController.player.currentItem seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime),60000)];
       [playerViewController.player play];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your currentTime value remains, then you need to add the tolerance part to resume from exact second.

```
[self.playerViewController.player.currentItem seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime),60000) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```